# Disabled Button when both field are selected at [0] position (Empty) from dropdown menu in JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable the buttons when I select empty fields from dropdown menu. If I select some value from the value then the  button should be enabled. Only in case I have selected the 2 fields as empty ([0] position), then only the button should be disabled. I want to use jQuery or JS for this.

Currently I was doing this -- but it is not working.

```
if ($('#roleid :selected').text()== "" && $('#userGroupId :selected').text()== "")
{

  document.getElementById('updaterole').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('updateUserGroup').disabled =true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this below

```
if ($('#roleid').val()== "" && $('#userGroupId').val()== "")
{

  document.getElementById('updaterole').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('updateUserGroup').disabled =true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($('#roleid').filter(':selected').text() == "" && $('#userGroupId').filter(':selected').text() == "")
{
    $('updaterole').prop("disabled", true);
    $('updateUserGroup').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: This is not working i am still able to click on that button. Can we do like this options[2].disabled = true; something like this ? how can we implement this?

Comment: if you give more context such as the html code for this JavaScript perhaps we can have a better view at your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".myddl").on("change", function () {
    var flag=false;
       $("select.myddl").each(function() {
         if($(this).val()){
             flag=true;
             return false
           }else{
             flag=false;
           }
        });
    if(!flag){
        document.getElementById('updaterole').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('updateUserGroup').disabled =true;
    }else{
         document.getElementById('updaterole').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('updateUserGroup').disabled =false;
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="first" class="myddl">
    <option value="">-- Select value --</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<select name="second" class="myddl">
    <option value="">-- Select value --</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
</br></br>

<button  id="updaterole" disabled>Button1</button>
<button  id="updateUserGroup" disabled>Button2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code fires on change of dropdowns:

```js
$('form select').on('change', function() {
  if ($("#ddl1 option:selected").text() == "" && $("#ddl2 option:selected").text()=="") {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  else{
  $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
      <select id="ddl1">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2">First Option</option>

      </select>
      <select id="ddl2">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2">First Option</option>

      </select>
      <input type="submit" name="btnGo" id="btnGo" value="Button1" class="btn disabled" style="width: 70px;"  />
      <input type="submit" name="btnGo" id="btnGo" value="Button1" class="btn disabled" style="width: 70px;" />
      <form>
```

**HTML Code :**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="ddl1">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2">First Option</option>

  </select>
  <select id="ddl2">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2">First Option</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="btnGo" id="btnGo" value="Button1" class="btn disabled" style="width: 70px;"  />
  <input type="submit" name="btnGo" id="btnGo" value="Button1" class="btn disabled" style="width: 70px;" />
  <form>
```